# Prove $1/2^1 + 2/2^2 +....+ n/2^n < 2$ using induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is another problem with induction that I'm sure requires some "thinking outside the box" which is something I cannot apply with my way of solving these problems.

I need to now how I can complete the induction step and I need a solution using induction.

Comment: Try to prove sth strong something like $S\leq 2-\frac{1}{n}$, for some $n\geq k$ then since sum is increasing then it holds also for $n<k$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $a_n=1/2+2/2^2+...+n/2^n$ then $$a_{n+1}=\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\right)+\frac{1}{2}a_n$$

So $a_{n+1}<1+\frac{1}{2}a_n$.

Comment: This is the best

Answer (score 2):

Suppose 
$\sum_\limits{k=1}^{\infty} k r^k$ converges  (and it does if r<1)

$S - rS = \sum_\limits{k=1}^{\infty} (n+1 - n) r^k = \sum_\limits{k=1}^{\infty}  r^k\\
S = \frac {r}{(1-r)^2}$

$\sum_\limits{k=1}^{\infty} k (\frac 12)^k = \frac {\frac 12}{(1-\frac 12)^2} = 2$

$\sum_\limits{k=1}^{n} k (\frac 12)^k < \sum_\limits{k=1}^{\infty} k (\frac 12)^k$

But that is not a proof by induction, is it?

Rather than prove that

$a_n = \frac 12 + \frac 24 \cdots + \frac {n}{2^n} < 2$ it will be easier if we try to prove something more restrictive.

Proposition:

$a_n = \frac 12 + \frac 24 \cdots + \frac {n}{2^n} = 2 - \frac {n+2}{2^n}$

Proof by induction:

base case:
n = 1

$\frac 12  = 2 - \frac {3}{2}$

Inductive hypothesis:

Suppose $a_n = \frac 12 + \frac 24 \cdots + \frac {n}{2^n} = 2 - \frac {n+2}{2^n}$

we will need to show:

$a_{n+1} <2-\frac {n+3}{2^{n+1}}$

$a_{n+1} = a_n + \frac {n+1}{2^{n+1}}\\
a_{n+1} = 2 - \frac {n+2}{2^n} + \frac {n+1}{2^{n+1}}$

Based on the inductive hypothesis

$a_{n+1} = $$2 - \frac {2(n+2)-(n+1)}{2^{n+1}}\\
2 - \frac {n+3}{2^{n+1}}\\
$

QED

Answer (score 2):

To use straight induction:

The basis is trivial: When $n=1$,
$$\frac1{2^1} = \frac12 < 1$$
Now suppose that for some natural number $n$,
$$\frac1{2^1}+\frac2{2^2}+\cdots+\frac{n}{2^n} < 2
$$
Then we can put all those terms over the same denominator $2^n$ to get, on the left hand side $\frac{k}{2^n}$ with $k\in\Bbb N$. Since this is less than $2$, 
$$\frac1{2^1}+\frac2{2^2}+\cdots+\frac{n}{2^n} \leq 2 - \frac1{2^n}$$

Then 
$$
\frac12\left(\frac1{2^1}+\frac2{2^n}+\cdots+\frac{n}{2^n} \right)< \frac12\left(2 - \frac1{2^n}\right) \\
\frac1{2^2}+\frac2{2^3}+\cdots+\frac{n}{2^{n+1}} \leq 1 - \frac1{2^{n+1}} 
$$
Now add to both sides:
$$
\frac1{2^1}+\frac1{2^n}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} = 1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \\
+\left[\frac1{2^2}+\frac2{2^3}+\cdots+\frac{n-1}{2^n}+\frac{n}{2^{n+1}}  \leq 1 - \frac1{2^{n+1}}\right]\\
$$ to get $$
\frac1{2^1}+\frac2{2^2}+\cdots+\frac{n}{2^n}+\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}} \leq 2-\frac1{2^n} < 2
$$
which establishes induction.

Comment: You don't really need that $-\frac{1}{2^n}$ part - if $a_n<2$ then $a_{n+1}<1+\frac{a_n}{2}<2$.

Comment: I do not understand how you got to the third step.